# Python percentage calculation in a column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

How do I add another column like this:

[image]

The value 49.11% equals to the sum of "country & city" group (30.2 + 20.8 + 10.5) multiplied by 30.2.

I use `groupby` and `sum()` to get the total of each (`country - city`) combination, but can't get the loop to fill in the percentage column.

Thanks.

Comment: @How did you got  the value `49.11%`?

Comment: Please attach your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for transform

```
df['percentage'] = df.groupby(['country', 'city'])['length'].transform(lambda z: z / z.sum() * 100)
```